# RestTemplate alternative for executing requests

Tags: spring-boot, rest, resttemplate

I need to execute a manual request within my Spring Boot application. With `RestTemplate` I would build my request and use `postForEntity` or `exchangeEntity` and it would work well. However `RestTemplate` is deprecated as of Spring 5 so I need to use something else. It needs body parameters as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not deprecated, it is "in maintenance mode"..."NOTE: As of 5.0 this class is in maintenance mode, with only minor requests for changes and bugs to be accepted going forward. Please, consider using the org.springframework.web.reactive.client.WebClient which has a more modern API and supports sync, async, and streaming scenarios."